# Kubernetes: Hit readinessProbe only once

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

I have following setting for readiness probe:

```
 readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /xyzapi/health
        port: 8888
      initialDelaySeconds: 30
      periodSeconds: 30
      timeoutSeconds: 30
      successThreshold: 2
      failureThreshold: 5
```

I want this readiness probe to be hit only once. It should fail or pass my deployment base on one try only.

I did some googling, but not much of help. Any kube expert? please help.

Comment: It sounds like your scenario does not require a readiness probe but an init container or entrypoint script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oswin Noetzelmann's comment is spot-on. The purpose of a readiness probe is to continually check for the state of readiness. You can probably still change it so that your readiness-check script checks once and then caches that result, but it wouldn't be idiomatic use of readiness.

Better alternatives for a one-time check are: init-containers or just using a wrapper script which wraps the actual work of your main container and performs the check you want.

I think it is a good use case for [init-containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#what-can-init-containers-be-used-for). From the documentation, one of the common purposes of init containers is:

> They run to completion before any app Containers start, whereas app
>   Containers run in parallel, so Init Containers provide an easy way to
>   block or delay the startup of app Containers until some set of
>   preconditions are met.

Comment: I have the same use case. I want zero downtime too. Will adding an init-container have zero downtime like readiness probe or will it have some downtime ? My readiness probe is cluttering the logs and I want the health check to not print logs to logs to cout.